# JavaScript: Array is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a multi-line variable and want to select a random line:

```
$.get('namelist.txt', function(nameList) {
  name = nameList.split('\n');
  var i = random();
  alert(name[i]); // this is undefined
});
```

The `random()` function returns a random number:

```
function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*201);
}
```

The problem is that the alert says `undefined`. If I replace line 3 with `var i = 5`, it works. I tested `i` with `typeof` and they're numbers in both cases. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe `name` have less than 200 elements?

Comment: Are there 200 items in the array?

Comment: You **really** want to put `var` in front of `name` in your function. Without it, unless you have `name` defined in the scope enclosing the code you've quoted, you're overwriting the `window.name` property (which is almost certainly not what you want). In general, be sure to declare your variables so as not to fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generate a random number depending on the length of the array. 201 is probably exceeding the highest index of your array.

You could adjust your random function to accept a length instead:

```
function random(len) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var name = nameList.split('\n');
var i = random(name.length);
alert(name[i]);
```

[Array documentation reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: as in function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*nameList.length);
}

Comment: Only remove `-1` from here :)

Comment: @Emmerman: If the array's length is 10 it could generate index 10, which would be to high. Because the indexes would range from 0 - 9.

Comment: @Kevin Nope. random() never returns 1 so it never return 10. And in your example you can get `-1` as a result

Comment: @Emmerman: It could indeed return -1, changed the function. Have a look :). (Random function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: @Kevin: Math.random() generates numbers less than one (e.g. 0.04) and if 'len' is 10, Math.floor(0.4) == 0.  If you subtract 1 from that, you'll have an invalid index.

Comment: @Kevin you made it even worse :) Because now with `len = 2` you'll alway get zero :)

Comment: Asked a question because I was doubting myself and my english: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580579/javascript-math-random

Answer (score 1):

Thsi is because the name is an array

which may contains around let say 3 element in it

if the random function have value more than 3 it will give you an error as you have right now.

on suggestion

first change no element in the array and the number generated by the random function.

```
if (name.length< randomnumber)
{
  //do logic what you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*name.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there are less than 201 lines of text in nameList.txt?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

var i = parseInt(random());

?

Comment: `Math.floor` doesn't return a string.