# Javascript Math.random()

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) in javascript **is** able to return 1, right? Which means if I would be to use it to get a random index on my array the following code could fail:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

// index could be 3?
alert(arr[index]);
```

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you even read the documentation you linked to? The answer is right there on the *first* sentence.

Comment: I did, but I wasn't sure what exclusive meant.

Comment: @Kevin: Then this question is off-topic and would have been better served on english.stackoverflow.com, posed purely as a language question.

Comment: wanna clear it in the separate topic? :) No, it can't be.

Comment: @Emmerman: Stack Overflow is not a forum; it has questions and answers, not "topics".

Comment: @Tomalak: You must mean `.stackexchange` (:? But I should've asked there, yes.

Comment: @Kevin: Er yes, that. :)

Comment: @Tomalak. Sorry, I'm not good in english too. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link you posted takes me to a site that says:

> Returns a pseudo-random number in the
>   range [0,1) — that is, between 0
>   (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). The
>   random number generator is seeded from
>   the current time, as in Java.

"inclusive" means the value is part of the range, whereas "exclusive" means that the value is *not* part of the range.

So `Math.random()` returns a value from 0 to just-less-than 1.

Answer (score 8):

No, it returns from 0 *inclusive* to 1 *exclusive*

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Note however the caveat in that page:

> Note that as numbers in JavaScript are
>   IEEE 754 floating point numbers with
>   round-to-nearest-even behavior, these
>   ranges, excluding the one for
>   Math.random() itself, aren't exact,
>   and depending on the bounds it's
>   possible in extremely rare cases (on
>   the order of 1 in 2<sup>62</sup>) to calculate
>   the usually-excluded upper bound.

For these purposes, though, you should be fine.

Comment: So my english has let me down :'(.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the number returned by

> Math.random()

is smaller than 1 but equal or greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (**exclusive**) - cannot be 1

Your code is all right