# Math.random array length +1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I don't understand something in this code :

```
vars.randAnim = anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length + 1))];
```

Let's say we have a new `Array`, with 5 elements, so from index 0 to index 4

Then let's say `Math.random()` returns 1. So, we've got the floor of `1*5`, but the 5 index doesn't exist in my `Array`, plus here we add a "+1"

Why +1? I would have expected exactly the opposite with "-1".

Comment: Somewhat duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580579/javascript-math-random

Comment: The `+1` is actually wrong here.  :-)

Comment: Lets say `Math.random()` returned .99, then, .99*5=4.95 then 4.95+1=5.95 then `Math.floor` will return 5 which will is out of bounds of the array. Therefore the question is:Why `+1` in the end?

Comment: The code +1 is wrong , as said Rocket. But also the reasoning has a flaw : Math.random() cannot return "1".

Comment: @Rocket @leonbloy @sv_in @Kevin : Thanks, is that really correct? math.random is never '1' ?? first time i hear about that, thanks a lot for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is wrong (as Rocket said). It should be

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length))
```

But also the reasoning has a flaw : Math.random() cannot return "1".

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random` does not return 1, it returns a value from 0 to 1.  `Math.floor` basically truncates the decimal off of the value.

So, if `Math.random` returns `0.3984753005206585` and multiply it by `4` we get `1.593901202082634` which becomes `1` after `Math.floor`.

When you want to get a random value from an array, you multiply `Math.random` by the length, so it will return values between 0 and the length (but never the length).

The `anims.length + 1` is incorrect in the above code.

Comment: This should be the top answer, very informative. Thanks Rocket