# Generate random letters in javascript and count how many times each letter has occurred?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate a string of random letters say 10 letters from a-z one after the other i.e. the next letter should be displayed after the previous letter after a certain delay, later, I want to calculate the number of times each letter has been generated, unlike what I have done previously, i.e. I have taken a predefined array of letters and generated them accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a string of 5 random characters in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: When should it count number of occurrences? Where should those numbers be printed. Clarify your question.

Comment: As soon as the string is generated ,
the no of occurrences may be counted,
and they could be displayed in a text box or a text area...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorter way to generate such a string using `String.fromCharCode`:

```
for (var i = 0, letter; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        letter = String.fromCharCode(97 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
        out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letter)); // append somewhere
    }, 2000 * i);
}
```

And complete demo covering all the problems in this question: http://jsfiddle.net/p8Pjq/

Comment: This doesn't count the letters.

Comment: @Guffa It does in the demo, I just didn't include the code in the answer.

Comment: Why don't you put the answer in the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `setInterval` method to run code at an interval. Set up an array for counting each character from the start, then you can count them when you create them instead of afterwards:

```
var text = '';
var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var cnt = new Array(chars.length);
for (var i = 0; i < cnt.length; i++) cnt[i] = 0;

var handle = window.setInterval(function(){
    var ch = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    cnt[ch]++;
    text += chars.charAt(ch);
    $('#display').text(text);
    if (text.length == 20) {
      window.clearInterval(handle);
      // now all characrers are created and counted
    }
}, 2000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R8rDH/

Comment: I was working on answering, but this seems like a better way than I was working on. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

I am stealing this answer, but look here: [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

```
function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

Comment: For Math.random() == 1, we would get a "" string. It should be possible.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * (possible.length - 1)));

Comment: @Parthik JavaScript's `Math.random` returns values in the range `[0,1)`, i.e. never exactly 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580579/javascript-math-random

Comment: @ParthikGosar: The `Math.random` method never returns 1. The random number is 0 <= n < 1. Using `round` for the random number means that the first and last character occurs half as often as they should.

Comment: Math.random never returns 1. EDIT: I was too slow, what they said is right.

Comment: thank you,
but thats not exactly what I m looking for,
consider the random string to be generated is AZXNYRAO,
then Z should be displayed 2 secs after A is displayed...
and then it should be calulated how many times each letter has occurred..
say
A=3,
X=1 so on...

Comment: @Phrogz, Guffa and JDewzy. Thanks. I din't know that !

Comment: so...
can any one please help me..?